# Overwhelming search results in pom.xml dependencies search

Tags: maven, pom.xml

Please take a look at this screenshot and help me find a way to only show relevant results. [Screenshot of problem description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3ROq.png)

Comment: Try http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cspring-core

Comment: I would like to use the search from the dependencies UI. Can I make it show only relevant results?

Comment: I don't see how. It seems to insist on approximate matches.

Comment: Guess I'll have to rely on google instead of pom.xml UI to search and find dependencies.

Comment: What do you mean by relevant?

Comment: show only results from let's say org.springframework or org.hibernate instead of all the other lists.

Comment: I have enabled full index on Maven global repositories. Could this be the reason?